# fetching protected or not in twitter api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I am working on an Twitter API. What I need to do is to check if the user is protected by default or not on tweeter Account `"protected":false`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `request` for other `user's` `timeline` in `twitter API`. The other users `timeline` will only be `visible` if they are `not` `protected`, or if the `authenticating` user's follow request was `accepted` by the `protected` user.

Refer [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) link for details.

Comment: ya i know it and make application according to it now when user enter wrong screen name that not exist on twitter or protected then my application is crash what should i do to stop it